# Laravel + Vue How do I send the selected value from the drop-down list to the database?

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

please tell me. I have two components. "AddFactorComponent.vue" is used to send the entered values to the "Database", there is also a built-in component "Factors_lists.vue", which serves as a drop-down list. The question is how to send the selected value from "Factors_lists.vue" to the database.

AddFactorComponent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="col-10">
    <div class="container-lg d-flex justify-content-center pt-1">
        <section class="data-tab" style="border: 1px solid white; width: 1200px">
            <div class="d-grid gap-2 d-md-flex justify-content-md-end">
                <a href="/"><button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" aria-label="Close"></button></a>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="factory_number" class="form-label">Factor evaluated by SI</label>
                <el-input v-model="factor" autosize type="textarea" placeholder=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2" >
                <label for="factory_number" class="form-label"Factor evaluated by SI</label>

            <Factors_lists ></Factors_lists>

            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label for="factory_number" class="form-label">Equipment ID</label>
                <el-input v-model="equipment_id " autosize type="textarea"
      placeholder=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="d-grid gap-2">
                <input @click.prevent="Add" class="btn third" value="Add">
            </div>
            <SpisokFactorComponent ref="spisok_factor_component"></SpisokFactorComponent>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Factors_lists.vue

```
<template>
    <select v-model="selectedfactors_list">Select your option
        <option v-for="factors_list in factors_lists" :key="factors_list.id" :value="factors_list.id">
            {{ factors_list.name }}
        </option>
    </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Factors_lists",
    data() {
        return {
            factors_lists: [],
            selectedfactors_list: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getPoluhenie();
    },
    methods: {
        getPoluhenie() {
            axios.get('/api/lists')
                .then(response => {
                    this.factors_lists = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Controller

```
class Factors_listsController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $items = Factors_lists::all();
        return response()->json($items);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AddFactorComponent.vue

```html
<template>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Factors_lists v-model="factor"></Factors_lists>
    <!-- ... -->
    <input @click.prevent="Add" class="btn third" value="Add" type="submit">
    <!-- ... -->
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        // ...
        data() {
            return {
                factor: null, // <- value from <select>
            };
        },
        // ...
        methods: {
            // ...,
            Add() {
                axios.post('/api/lists', {factor: this.factor}) // <- sending the value from <select>
            },
            // ...
        },
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

Factors_lists.vue

```html
<script>
    export default {
        // ...
        props: {
            value: { // <- waiting the value from AddFactorComponent.vue via `v-model`
                type: null,
                required: true,
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                factors_lists: [],
                selectedfactors_list: null, // <- remove this line because it has migrated to `computed`
            }
        },
        computed: {
            selectedfactors_list: {
                get() {
                    return this.value; // get value for <select> from AddFactorComponent.vue
                },
                set(value) {
                    this.$emit('input', value); // send the new value to AddFactorComponent.vue
                }
            }
        },
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

Factors_listsController

```php
// ...
public function store(Request $request) {
    $factor = $request->input('factor'); // the value from vue
}
// ...
```

routes/api.php

```php
Route::post('/api/lists', [Factors_listsController::class, 'store']);
```

You need to read the documentation:

- [vue.js v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)
- [vue.js props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#ad)
- [vue.js emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)
- [laravel controllers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#main-content)